# Submitting a form from one model's controller and view to a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller, routes

I'm new to Rails and working on a sample app. The idea behind the app is that it's a computerized check-in sheet for kids to ride a school bus. There are four models: Family, Kid, SchoolRide, and HomeRide. For Family and Kid, I generated complete scaffolds, but for SchoolRide and HomeRide, they're just models with a boolean field each of whether the kid has checked in to the schoolbus in the morning or checked out in the afternoon when coming home.

I want to be able to have a user check in a kid from a form rendered on the kid show view, but I'm having trouble creating instances of my ride models from the kids controller. How do I set up the views, routing, and controllers? Where/how do I pass in the parameters to the ride models in the kids controller?

Here's my form rendered into the kid's show view. Currently, I'm getting a syntax error.

```
<%= form_with(model: @school_ride, remote: true), :url => school_rides_path, :html => { :method => :post } do |form| %>
<div><p>
  <%= form.label :check_in %><br>
  <%= form.check_box :check_in %><br>
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <%= form.hidden_field :kid_id, value: @kid.id %>
</div>

<p>
  <%= form.submit %>
</p> 
<% end %>
```

Here're my models:

```
class Kid < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :family
  has_many :school_rides
  has_many :home_rides
end


class HomeRide < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :kid
end

class SchoolRide < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :kid
end
```

Here are some relevant parts of my kids controller:

```
def show
    @family = Family.all
    @school_ride = SchoolRide.new
  end

  # GET /kids/new
  def new
    @kid = Kid.new
  end

  # GET /kids/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /kids
  # POST /kids.json
  def create
    @kid = Kid.new(kid_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @kid.save
        format.html { redirect_to family_path(id: @kid.family_id), notice: 'Kid was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @kid }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @kid.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end


  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_kid
    @kid = Kid.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def kid_params
    params.require(:kid).permit(:name, :birthdate, :grade, :family_id)
  end  

  def school_ride_params
    params.require(:school_ride).permit(:check_in)
  end
```

Here's some of my routing:

```
  resources :kids

 resources :school_rides, only: [:new, :create]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%=form_for @school_rid, remote: true do |form| %>
```

Comment: No, that didn't work.

I had this in my code earlier:
`<%= form_with(model: @school_ride, remote: true) do |form| %>`...

which is similar to what you have, and the form would at least load without error, but clicking on the "submit" wouldn't write to the database. That's why I added the `url` and `html` parts, but now I'm getting the syntax error.

Comment: Could you pass me the error that throws you? Thank you!

Comment: app/views/kids/_formtoschool.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end  
app/views/kids/_formtoschool.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting &. or :: or '[' or '.'  
app/views/kids/_formtoschool.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end  
app/views/kids/_formtoschool.html.erb:21: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input  
app/views/kids/show.html.erb:41:in `_app_views_kids_show_html_erb___142926224_113431320'

Comment: I apologize for the delay, I was at work; try the following:
`<%= form_with model: @school_ride, remote: true do |form| %>`

Comment: That gets the error to go away, but when I hit "submit," nothing really happens. No changes are written to the SchoolRide database.

Comment: Ok, that may be because it does not have to answer with js, remove the `remote: true` to debug that and tell me. You need to add a format.js in your create action and to this a view with the name of the action but .js

Comment: I removed the `remote: true` and have the same issue. No syntax error this time, but no writing to the database either. Admittedly, I'm not sure what that `remote: true` even does. I copied that from some other code.

Comment: What `remote: true` does is send the request async and respond with JS, this is used when you want to do things in real time, but, if you do not specify in your controller that you can also respond with JS and indicate a view to that function I will not know what to do;  Another error that I see is that in your form you have a hidden_field, assuming that you want to load it in db before you should give it the permission in your school_ride_params method; 
Gather all the things that I was telling you and compile (without the remote: true, and the form declared as I did above in the comments)

Comment: In the kid controller, I have `@school_ride = SchoolRide.new` in the `def new` method, and I have `school_ride_params` as a private method, but I realize I don't pass the params anywhere the CRUD.  Where should the params go?

Comment: In the new method only declare variable: '@kid = Kid.new' and pass the params in create method like: @kid = Kid.new(kid_params), that you have it right, now that error is throwing you?

Comment: The kid forms and controller with `@kid = Kid.new` and `@kid = Kid.new(kid_params)` are working fine. The issue here is I'm trying to create an instance of an `@school_ride` but I don't have a controller for its model. The larger question still remains, How to I write to a model from a form directly? That's why I have `:url => school_rides_path, :html => { :method => :post } ` in my version of the form, but it's not working.